# Since the destruction does the Shechinoh dwell in the world? Kinoh suggests no; halocho suggests yes

Tags: minyan, churban-destruction, shechinah

[Kinoh 12 of the day of 9th of Av](https://www.sefaria.org/Kinnot_for_Tisha_B%27Av_(Ashkenaz)%2C_Kinot_for_Tisha_B%27Av_Day.12.18-21?lang=bi) refers to the destruction of the Temple and the fact that G-d's presence (Shechinoh) is no longer to be found in this world.

> אָהֳלִי אֲשֶׁר כּוֹנַנְתָּ מוּל מָכוֹן לְשִׁבְתְּךָ לְחוֹפֵף לְחֻפּוֹ.
>
> My temple which You established for Your residence to overshadow it
> like a canopy
>
> לָמָּה לָנֶצַח יֻעָה בְּיַד יְהִירִים.
>
> why is it swept away by arrogant ones
>
> וְנִהְיֵיתָ כְּטָס בֶּחָלָל וְאֵין עוֹד נָבִיא.
>
> While You have become like a wanderer in space and there is no more a
> prophet
>
> וְנַמְתָּ הַאֵין פֹּה:
>
> for You said no (prophet) shall be here.

The fifth stanza refers to G-d as being כְּטָס בֶּחָלָל like a wanderer in space.

How is it then that we find that the Divine Presence is to be found where there is a minyan? See [Sh O, O Ch 124 (3) MB 15](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.124.3?lang=bi&with=Mishnah%20Berurah&lang2=en)

> שכיון שיש עשרה ישנה שם השכינה
>
> since once there are ten, the Shechinoh is there.

Comment: Its also with a chosson and kallah....זכו שכינה ביניהן (Sotah 17a)

Comment: I would imagine that perhaps it means that it doesn't dwell in a permanent fashion like it did when there was a beis hamikdosh, but Hashem allows it to 'wander' for various scenarios such minyan, a happy marital home etc.

Comment: There is a concept of Shechina in each of the 4 worlds. Perhaps, the Shechina is in exile in relation to one world and can be found by a Minyan or other instances in relation to a different Olam.     https://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/1410035/jewish/Four-Levels-of-Shechinah-in-Exile-213.htm

Comment: here is another explanation that expounds on two levels of Shechina, one for the Bais Hamikdash and one for Exile

Comment: I think it is just a matter of degrees.

Comment: Even a (human or alien) "wanderer in space" still lands sometimes...